# Javascript - Error when scrolling to bottom of page

Tags: javascript

Doing tests through Firebug/Firefox, I'm attempting to run the simplest of commands to have the page scroll to the bottom using the following command:

```
window.scrollBy(0,3000);
```

Simple, right? Doing a test on a couple websites, for example Yahoo.com, the small line of code works perfectly. However, on one specific site that I'm attempting to run this on, the page does not scroll I get this in my console log.

```
>>> window.scrollBy(0,3000);
undefined
```

The page I'm testing automatically has jQuery 1.7.2 running on it. What could I send through my console to fix this error? I'm suspecting to 'define window' again?

Comment: What page are you testing that on.  They probably have an `onscroll` event bound.

Comment: https://signup.live.com/signup.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=11&ct=1359488007&rver=6.1.6206.0&wp=MBI&wreply=http%3a%2f%2fmail.live.com%2fdefault.aspx&id=64855&cbcxt=mai&snsc=1&bk=1359488008&uiflavor=web&mkt=EN-US&lc=1033&lic=1

If onscroll is bound, is there a piece of jQuery that could do the same thing?

Comment: It's not the window that's being scrolled, it's the `c_base` div.  The page is the height of the window, you're actually scrolling the div's overflow, not the window.  Check this demo I made: http://jsfiddle.net/UAkpT/

Comment: Ah now I see it! How would I go about scrolling the overflow so I end up at the bottom of the page?

Comment: Why are you trying to scroll that page anyway?  Are you trying to make an extension?  What's your real goal here?

Comment: I'm creating an small script for students registering Live accounts required for a course. Their student information will automatically be filled in, all they have to enter themselves is their phone number, zipcode, and the captcha. I want to autoscroll as it was a request from my prof. He wants everything custom, no using other already developed extensions.

Comment: You can try setting the element's `scrollTop` property.  `document.getElementById('c_base').scrollTop = 3000;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.scrollBy` isn't working on the page you are [trying it on](https://signup.live.com/signup.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=11&ct=1359488007&rver=6.1.6206.0&wp=MBI&wreply=http://mail.live.com/default.aspx&id=64855&cbcxt=mai&snsc=1&bk=1359488008&uiflavor=web&mkt=EN-US&lc=1033&lic=1), because it's not window that's overflowed and is scrolling.

The `c_base` div on the page is what's being scrolled.  It's absolutely positioned, and its overflow is what you are scrolling, not the entire window.

You can scroll the div by setting it's `scrollTop` property:

```
document.getElementById('c_base').scrollTop = 3000;
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not an error, `undefined` in your console after calling this function means that it just doesn't return anything.

Comment: Issue is that it doesn't scroll, however.